# emacs で段階的に xml を unfold していくことはできるか

Tags: emacs

emacs で、 xml を段階的に unfold していくことはできますか？
段階的な unfold とは、たとえば次のような挙動です。

1. 最初はトップレベルの xml のノードがだけが表示されていて、
    その中身は省略されている
2. 任意のノードをより詳細表示するようなコマンドが利用可能で、
    これを利用すると、１段階分だけノードが展開されて表示される。

今できていることとしては、 nXML-mode + hs-minor-mode で、任意の node の hide/show が可能なのですが、xml の全容を俯瞰的に理解しながら気になるところを詳細に調べていくことをやる際に、まず最初にすべての top level の node を hide することからはじめたりしているので、若干不便だと感じているからです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web-mode の `C-c C-f` (`web-mode-fold-or-unfold`), `C-c C-e f` (`web-mode-element-children-fold-or-unfold`) を利用するとやりたいことができました。